# connecting dateway 4108 grandstream to elastix

Tags: gateway, inbound, elastix

i have a 4108 grand stream gateway. its connected to "Elastix" and my outbound is correct. but my inbound after two dialing and beep not work. and my call stay unfinished.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what youre asking here.  Perhaps, Take a look at the faq stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: exuse me, my english language isnt good. so icant ask currectly my question   ):

Comment: Ok.  Type it up in your language, and convert it to English at  https://translate.google.com/ , and I will update the question so its clearer...